# Round number to two decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use `Math.round` for the *total* to show only two decimals, but it doesn't work as intended. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalPrice = 0;

    $('.food').click(function() {
        var $frm = $(this).parent();
        var toAdd = $frm.children(".productInput").val();
        var addPrice = parseFloat($frm.children(".priceInput").val());
        var addAmount = parseFloat($frm.children(".amountInput").val());

        if ($('.priceInput').val() == '') {
            alert('Price can not be left blank');
        };
        if ($('.amountInput').val() == '') {
            alert('Amount can not be left blank');
        } else {

            var div = $("<div>");
            div.append("<p class='amount'>" + addAmount + "</p>", "<p class='product'> " + toAdd + " </p>", "<p class='price'>" + addPrice + "</p>", "<p class='delete'>" + "X" + "</p>");

            $frm.parent().children(".messages").append(div);

            totalPrice += addAmount * addPrice;

            $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);
        }


        console.log(addAmount);
        console.log(addPrice);
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
        /*         var subAmount = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".amount").text());
                    var subPrice = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".price").text());
                    totalPrice -= subAmount * subPrice;
                    $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);*/

        $(this).closest("div").remove();
        console.log(subPrice);
        console.log(subAmount);
    });

    $(document).on("mouseover", ".delete", function() {
        var hoverAmount = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".amount").text());
        var hoverPrice = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".price").text());
        totalPrice -= hoverAmount * hoverPrice;
        Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100
        $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);

        $(this).closest("div").fadeTo("fast", 0.4);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseout", ".delete", function() {
        var subAmount = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".amount").text());
        var subPrice = parseFloat($(this).siblings(".price").text());
        totalPrice += subAmount * subPrice;
        Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100
        $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + totalPrice);


        $(this).closest("div").fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
    })





    });
```

Since I'm using float, the numbers sometimes get changed into long decimals instead of the exact amount. I'm trying to prevent this by using Math.round. If anyone have another solution to the problem that would be appreciated too.

Comment: i think you should use variable for Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100. For ex: var result = Math.round(totalPrice * 100) / 100;  $(".totalPrice").text("Total Price: $" + result);

Comment: [`totalPrice.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) with `2` as argument, in order to round it to two decimals.
Just, remember that the returned value is a String:

```js
let totalPrice = 4.655555;

totalPrice = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
console.log(totalPrice);        // "4.66"
console.log(typeof totalPrice); // string
```

If you want to return a number, use `Number(totalPrice.toFixed(2))` — just keep in mind that i.e: `Number((7.005).toFixed(2))` will return `7` (without the decimal part)

Answer (score 0):

If you work with currency it is better to use fixed point numbers for precision. There is no fixed-point number type in javascript, so consider using external libraries.
E.g. [Big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js) or [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

Comment: Thank you, that is something I will definitely look into when I'm more comfortable with javascript, still a beginner :)