# How to round decimals to integers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a full number (integer) whereas the output is always decimal. How do I change this?

I've tried searching on stack overflow but can't find a similar issue

```
// Javscript exercise taken from internet for absolute beginners

var people = prompt("how many people are there? ");
var pizzas = prompt("How many pizzas are there? ");
const slices = 8;

var perPerson = ((pizzas * slices) / people);

var leftovers = perPerson % 2;

if (leftovers !== 0) { 
    Math.round(leftovers);
}

prompt(`There are a total of ${people} people with ${pizzas} pizzas`);
prompt(`Each person gets ${perPerson} slices of pizza`);
prompt(`There are ${leftovers} leftover slices of pizza`);
```

I was expecting whole numbers but I am only getting decimals

Comment: `Math.round(leftovers)` does not modify `leftovers`. It will *return* the rounded value of `leftovers`, but currently you aren't capturing it. If you want to overwrite the current value of `leftovers` with the rounded version, you'd do `leftovers = Math.round(leftovers)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math.round not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242234/math-round-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to reset `leftovers` like this in `leftovers=Math.round(leftovers);`

```
var people = prompt("how many people are there? ");
    var pizzas = prompt("How many pizzas are there? ");
    const slices = 8;

    var perPerson = ((pizzas * slices) / people);

    var leftovers = perPerson % 2;

    if (leftovers !== 0) {
        leftovers=Math.round(leftovers);
    }

    prompt(`There are a total of ${people} people with ${pizzas} pizzas`);
    prompt(`Each person gets ${perPerson} slices of pizza`);
    prompt(`There are ${leftovers} leftover slices of pizza`);
```